# Create subscription with addon using node-recurly

Tags: node.js, recurly

Using [node-recurly](https://github.com/cgerrior/node-recurly), I can create a subscription object and pass it to `recurly.subscriptions.create` call:

```
const subscription = {
      plan_code: plan.code,
      currency: 'USD',
      account: {
        account_code: activationCode,
        first_name: billingInfo.first_name,
        last_name: billingInfo.last_name,
        email: billingInfo.email,
        billing_info: {
          token_id: paymentToken,
        },
      },
    };
```

I would also like to add `subscription_add_ons` property, which, looking at [the documentation](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/subscription-add-ons), supposed to be an array of add-ons. I tried passing it like this:

```
subscription_add_ons: [
        {
            add_on_code: shippingMethod.servicelevel_token,
            unit_amount_in_cents: parseFloat(shippingMethod.amount) * 100,
        },
      ],
```

The server returned an error:

> Tag <subscription_add_ons> must consist only of sub-tags named
>   <subscription_add_on>

I attempted this:

```
subscription_add_ons: [
        {
          subscription_add_on: {
            add_on_code: shippingMethod.servicelevel_token,
            unit_amount_in_cents: parseFloat(shippingMethod.amount) * 100,
          },
        },
      ],
```

Got back this error:
[image]

What's the proper format to pass subscription add on in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper format is:

```
subscription_add_ons: {
        subscription_add_on: [{
          add_on_code: shippingMethod.servicelevel_token,
          unit_amount_in_cents: parseFloat(shippingMethod.amount) * 100,
        }],
      },
```

Comment: This works for 1 add on. Any idea how to accomplish this with more than 1 add on?

Comment: the subscription_add_on is an array. Try adding your additional add-ons there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this which works whether you have 1 add-on or multiple add-ons. subscription_add_ons is an array which can contain 1 or more subscription add ons. I then send over the details (along with other info) in the subscription update call. This is similar to what you attempted in your original post so I'm not sure why that didn't work for you.

```
details.subscription_add_ons = [
    { subscription_add_on: {add_on_code: "stream", quantity: 3} },
    { subscription_add_on: {add_on_code: "hold", quantity: 2} }
];
```